# How to know if web content cannot be handled by Scrapy?

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, scrapy

I apologize if my question sounds too basic or general, but it has puzzled me for quite a while. I am a political scientist with little IT background. My own research on this question does not solve the puzzle.

It is said that Scrapy cannot scrape web content generated by JavaScript or AJAX. But how can we know if certain content falls in this category? I once came across some texts that show in Chrome Inspect, but could not be extracted by Xpath (I am 99.9% certain my Xpath expression was correct). Someone mentioned that the texts might be hidden behind some JavaScript. But this is still speculation, I can't be totally sure that it wasn't due to wrong Xpath expressions. Are there any signs that can make me certain that this is something beyond Scrapy and can only be dealt with programs such as Selenium? Any help appreciated.

-=-=-=-=-=

Edit (1/18/15): The webpage I'm working with is http://yhfx.beijing.gov.cn/webdig.js?z=5. The specific piece of information I want to scrape is circled in red ink (see screenshot below. Sorry, it's in Chinese).

[image]

I can see the desired text in Chrome's Inspect, which indicates that the Xpath expression to extract it should be `response.xpath("//table/tr[13]/td[2]/text()").extract()`. However, the expression doesn't work.

I examined `response.body` in Scrapy shell. The desired text is not in it. I suspect that it is JavaScript or AJAX here, but in the html, I did not see signs of JavaScript or AJAX. Any idea what it is?

Comment: The ultimate scraper: https://www.import.io/

Comment: Well, you can be sure something is generated by JS if it is not there in the HTML source (and, of course, if there is JS code in it). As for the XPath expression that is 99.9% correct - why not show it to us instead of saying you've seen the [unicorn in the garden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unicorn_in_the_Garden)? And also show the HTML that you were trying to select from.

Comment: @MathiasMüller, you are right. I edited my post and provided the url. Any help appreciated.

Comment: @JosephZhou I prefer to use a "find the value by label" approach: `response.xpath("//td[contains(.,"text in the label")]/following-sibling::td/text()")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is said that Scrapy cannot scrape web content generated by JavaScript or AJAX. But how can we know if certain content falls in this category?

The browsers do a lot of things when you open a web page. I will be oversimplify the process here:

1. Performs an HTTP request to the server hosting the web page.
2. Parses the response, which in most cases is HTML content (text-based format). We will assume we get a HTML response.
3. Starts the rendering the HTML, executes the Javascript code, retrieves external resources (images, css files, js files, fonts, etc). Not necessarily in this order.
4. Listens to events that may trigger more requests to inject more content into the page.

Scrapy provides tools to do 1. and 2. Selenium and other tools like [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.org/) do 3., allow you to do 4. and access the rendered HTML.

Now, I think there are three basic cases you face when you want to extract *text content* from a web page:

1. The text is in plain HTML format, for example, as a text node or HTML attribute: `<a>foo</a>`, `<a href="foo" />`. The content could be visually hidden by CSS or Javascript, but as long is part of the HTML tree we can extract it via XPath/CSS rules.
2. The content is located in Javascript code. For example: `<script>var cfg = {code: "foo"};</script>`. We can locate the `<script>` node with a XPath rule and then use regular expressions to extract the string we want. Also there are libraries that allow us to *parse* pieces of Javascript so we can load objects easily. A complex solution here is executing the javascript code via a javascript engine.
3. The content is located in a external resource and is loaded via Ajax/XHR. Here you can emulate the XHR request with Scrapy and the parse the output, which can be a nice JSON object, arbitrary javascript code or simply HTML content. If it gets tricky to reverse engineer how the content is retrieved/parsed then you can use Selenium or Splash as a proxy for Scrapy so you can access the rendered content and still be able to use Scrapy for your crawler.

How you know which case you have? You can simply lookup the content in the response body:

```
$ scrapy shell http://example.com/page
...
>>> 'foo' in response.body.lower()
True
```

If you see `foo` in the web page via the browser but the test above returns `False`, then it's likely the content is loaded via Ajax/XHR. You have to check the network activity in the browser and see what requests are being done and what are the responses. Otherwise you are in case 1. or 2. You can simply view the source in the browser and search for the content to figure out where is located.

Let say the content you want is located in HTML tags. How do you know if your XPath expression *correct*? (By correct here we mean that gives you the output you expect)

Well, if you do `scrapy shell` and `response.xpath(expression)` returns nothing, then your XPath is not correct. You should reduce the specificity of your expression until you get an output that includes the content you want, and then narrow it down.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your detailed answer. I did the check you suggested and I believe my problem is Case 3. But could you further illuminate how to check network activity in the browser and make sure it's Ajax/XHR? There is a post on StackOverFlow on this subject but I cannot grasp what to look for. Thanks very much!

Comment: @JosephZhou depends on your browser but basically, open the inspector in your browser, select the `network` tab and refresh/open your target page, then you can filter XHR requests. There you can see the request payload and response content. Another less likely scenario is having the content generated by an external javascript (not XHR request), to find this I would download the entire web page and search (grep) the files for the content hint. You may need to "beautify" the javascript files.